# .isin() only returning one value as opposed to entire list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, isin

I have a large pandas dataframe with ~500,000 rows and 6 columns and each row is uniquely identified by the 'Names' column. The other 5 columns contain characteristic information about the correpsonding 'Names' entry. I also have a separate list of ~40,000 individual names, all of which are subsumed within the larger dataframe. I want to use this smaller list to extract all of the corresponding infromation in the larger dataframe, and am using:

```
info = df[df['Names'].isin(ListNames)]
```

where df is the large dataframe and ListNames is the list of names I want to get the information for. However, when I run this, only one row is extracted from the overall dataframe as opposed to ~40000. I have also tried using ListNames as a 'Series' datatype instead of 'List' datatype but this returned the same thing as before. Would be super grateful for any advice - thanks!

Comment: Looks like you have a issue with the match, it should work (but there should be an **exact** match). Can you provide a sample of the dataframe and the list?

Comment: did you check the values of the names column for leading or trailing whitespaces ? or case sensitivities ?

Comment: yep it was a white space at the end of the strings in the dataframe column that I didn't realise existed until you suggested, that's perfect now, thanks for the help!